# beamer: slide number instead of frame number?

Tags: beamer, numbering, frame

I'm using the following code. The problem is, that the slides getting counted and not the frames. Can someone help?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%Style
\mode<presentation>{
    %Theme
    \usetheme{Goettingen}
    
%Farb-Theme
\usecolortheme{rose}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Navigations-Symbole entfernen
%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % Fußzeile entfernen
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % Fußzeile entfernen und durch Folien-Zahl ersetzen
}

%Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %deutsche Umlaute
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %deutsche Sprache
\usepackage{graphicx} %für Bilder
\usepackage{booktabs} %für \toprule \midrule \bottomrule in Tabellen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


% https://www.mlte.de/downloads/beamer/centeredTitlepage/
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
% change the meaning of the letter @
\makeatletter
% define new command plain
\newcommand{\plain}[1]{\frame[plain,t]{%
        % move current position to remove left margin
        \hspace*{-\beamer@leftmargin}%
        % create minipage of full paperwith to remove right margin
        \minipage[c][\textheight]{\paperwidth}%
        #1%
        % add paragraph to keep vertical (fill) space at the end of the minipage
        \par\vskip\z@%
        \endminipage%
}}
% reset the meaning of the letter @
%\makeatother


%Einstellungen der Titelseite der Präsentation
\title[]{Titel}
\subtitle{Untertitel}
\author{Max Mustermann}
\institute{Musteruniversität}
\date{Musteruniversität, Hörsaal XX\\ \today}

\begin{document}
    %Titelseite
    \plain{\maketitle}
%   \begin{frame}\titlepage\end{frame}
        
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Motivation}
\begin{frame}{Motivation}%Setzt eine Überschrift mit dem Text {} oben links auf der Folie
    Text:\\ \pause
    \begin{itemize} 
        \item[--]{Text 1}\pause 
        \item[--]{Text 2} \pause
        \item[--]{Text 3}\pause
        \item[--]{Text 4}\pause
    \end{itemize}   
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Motivation}%Setzt eine Überschrift mit dem Text {} oben links auf der Folie
Text:\\ \pause
\begin{itemize} 
    \item[--]<2->{Text 1}   
    \item[--]<3->{Text 2} 
    \item[--]<4->{Text 3}
    \item[--]<5->{Text 4}
\end{itemize}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you missing after having compiled twice? A "slide" is the old-fashioned framed piece of photographic film to which nowadays (without the physical frame) is referred to as "frame".

Comment: If I compile the code I get total 13 frames and not 3. See also https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=23950 and than press button "LaTex-Ausgabe"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
\newcounter{frame}[frame]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
```

Comment: Thank's! That's it. I tried "frame" instead of "page" without your first line of code. That didn't work. With the first line it works.